# What does "must reside at the top level of the app bundle" in Apple Document mean?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I always find the saying in somewhere of apple documents.

e.g.

> [UILaunchImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW28):
>
> A string containing the name of the PNG image file. **The image file must reside at the top level of the app bundle**. The name you specify for this key should not include a filename extension, nor should it include modifiers such as @2x, -568h, ~iphone, or ~ipad.

What does "must reside at the top level of the app bundle" mean? Where is the "top level"?

Answer (score 1):

Top level of the app bundle is the root level (directory) of your bundle. You can have a look at the image below [image]

Also you can find more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html)